# Only show columns where the cell value is higher than 0 for a group of rows

Tags: excel, vba, hide

I am currently creating a competence matrix which should have some functionality installed that it only shows the relevant columns for a certain department. Within a department a group of people is working and performing a X number of tasks where they are skilled for. The sum of tasks for all departments is so high the the overview will be lost if each department has to look for data in all columns.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to only display the columns for a department where one of the columns at least contains a number higher than 0 (which is equal to untrained/not in scope for that department). By that the columns should only remain that are applicable to that department.

See below screenshot for an impression of the competence matrix:
[image]

Example code:

```
Department,Expedition,WAC,Unpacker,Stagnation,Runner,Runner MLX
D2S,5,5,3,5,0,5
D2S,5,2,0,5,0,5
S2F,0,0,4,5,0,0
S2F,0,0,1,0,0,5
```

Above code more or less does the trick already, but this is not dynamic. As soon as a column is inserted, the hidden columns are not correct anymore. Also, it should contain the functionality where people will be crosstrained and thus more columns need to be visible as soon as people are trained for a process that currently does not belong to a certain department. Below code does not suffice this option:

```
Public Sub Hide_Department_Columns(dataSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim Department As String
    
    With dataSheet
    
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
        
            Department = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1, 5).Value  '5 is column E
        
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
            Select Case Department
            
                Case "D2S"
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False  'unhide all columns
                    .Range("AA:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                
                Case "S2F"
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False
                    .Range("AI:AI,AN:AZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    
                Case "S2F - 5 Shift"
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False
                    .Range("AG:AG,AN:AQ,AV:AX,BA:BJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                
                Case "F2S"
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False
                    .Range("AS:AS,BK:BT").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    
                Case "EHV1"
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False
                    .Range("AB:AB,BM:BM,BU:CC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    
                 Case "Best2"
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False
                    .Range("AB:AB,BM:BM,BU:BW,BY:CB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                
                Case Else
                    .Columns("A:Z").Hidden = False
                
            End Select
            
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Can someone help me in how I would build in this functionality. I am thinking of something like: If column F value is filtered a certain department (E.G.) and if any value within range AB13:CD:2000 is higher than 0 show that column.

I tried the code used, but it does not suffice the dynamic function.

Comment: Maybe someone will take the time to painstakingly copy your screenshot into a worksheet. But you may get more interested if you read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and then edit your question to post sample data as text which can be copy/pasted.

Comment: Thank you Ron Rosenfield, I have added a small piece of the Excel that shows the principle of the matrix.

Comment: A VBA macro cannot be dynamic unless you tie it to a worksheet change or worksheet calculate event. Perhaps a formula solution?

Comment: Data is from A1 to D50, where the header is in row 1.   The manual process : after the user filter the data by column A, he click column B and see the sum result in bottom right of the Excel App is 0, so he hide column B. Then he click column C, he see the sum is bigger than 0, so nothing to do. Then he click column D, he see the sum is 0, so he hide this column. Goal : after a user filter the data by column A, he run the macro and the expected result: of the filtered data, from column B to D, if the sum of each column is 0 then hide the column. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Is there a way to select which one department (or which ones) to be shown?

Comment: Your workflow isn't clear to me. Maybe make your matrix a `Table`. Add a Totals row and copy the `SUBTOTAL(109,...` formula to all the cells in the Totals row. Then, after filtering, you just need to scan that row for 0's, and then hide the columns where it appears.

Comment: Thank you all, I solved it by the logic of Ron. Created a macro button per department which only shows indeed the columns where the sum of the column was higher than 0. The logic from Karma is the logic I was using indeed.